# How to remove duplicate entries to get unique elements when using collection_select? Getting error - any idea why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, duplicates

I am trying to do something somewhat common - generate an array of unique items in a list on a  form when using `collection_select`.  A User `has many` payments, and a Payment `belongs_to` user.  I am using Devise and so know the `current_user`.

I can **successfully** generate a list of emails **with duplication** in the view using the code:

```
<%= form_for(@payment) do |f| %>
.
.
.
   <%= f.collection_select :email, current_user.payment, :email, :email, {:include_blank => "Please select"} %>
```

However, I have not been able to get the same list of emails eliminating duplicates.  This question has been asked a few times on Stackoverflow, but I have not had success implementing the other solutions.  I have tried (without luck):

```
<%= f.collection_select :email, current_user.payment.collect(&:email).uniq, :email, :email, {:include_blank => "Please select"} %>
<%= f.collection_select :email, current_user.payment.pluck(:email).uniq, :email, :email, {:include_blank => "Please select"} %>
```

I get the error message **undefined method 'email' for "test@example.com":String**.  Can anyone help me understand (1) why the code I am using is incorrect, and (2) what change to make in the code?

Greatly appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: try using compact.uniq instead of .uniq because .uniq treats nil as an unique entry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand the error (question 1):
`collection_select` expects a collection of objects, and sends the value and label methods to these objects.

After `collect` or `pluck`, you have an **array of strings**, so sending the value or label method `:mail` to this string gives your error.

To solve this, refine the relation that is returned by `current_user.payments`:

```
<%= f.collection_select :email, current_user.payment.select(:email).uniq, :email, :email, {:include_blank => "Please select"} %>
```

`uniq`, as part of relations, only works with Rails 3.2 or later. With earlier Rails versions it is:

```
<%= f.collection_select :email, current_user.payment.select('distinct email'), :email, :email, {:include_blank => "Please select"} %>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!  And appreciate the explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is dated, but if calling .uniq does not remove the duplication, calling .distinct can also provide a solution here:

```
 <%= f.collection_select :email, current_user.payments.select(:email).distinct, :email, :email, {:include_blank => "Please select"} %>
```

Comment: Can you explain how .distinct avoids the errors that questioner noticed?